# change bootsrap to a free theme downloaded bootstrap in mvc asp

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I downloaded a free theme bootstrap to bootstrap file in a MVC project and change 
bootstrap file to bootstrap-def to have its backup but it does not apply free theme on my PC.

Comment: Please clarify the question to a specific issue, and include the relevant code.

Comment: @ZimSystem it does not need any code. it is a free theme and just have to replace in a folder. just it

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Content folder in Visual Studio and go to Add > Existing Item then add the file.

Comment: I added a style sheet in content folder and named it to bootstrap that is why I wonder why it does not apply.

Comment: when you browse the site hit ctrl+f5 to force a full refresh - see if that helps.